# How to show changed image after dowloading it in SVG in React?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, image

I'm trying to figure out how to show an image in another page after you have clicked on download button. The application itself is a Meme generator where you can add your own text. Adding text and downloading it works perfectly. I also have a way to like the memes and save the likes on firebase. I have another page that displays memes that have more than 10 likes. But I want to show memes that users have added text to and have some way to display them after the user has downloaded it.

The code I'm using to download looks like this. This excludes the return statement that attaches the text added to the meme.

```
saveMeme = () => {
    let name = document.getElementById("memename").value
    name.length > 0 ?
        svg.saveSvgAsPng(document.getElementById("svg_ref"), `${name}.png`) :
        svg.saveSvgAsPng(document.getElementById("svg_ref"), "meme.png")
};
```

My question is what could I add here to have the changed image be displayed.?

My code for liking the memes looks like this(if it's useful)

```
getMemesWithHigherLikes = () => {
     let memesWithLikes = [];
     const { memeLikesList, images} = this.props;

for (let i = 0; i < memeLikesList.length; i++) {
  if (memeLikesList[i]?.likes >= 10) {
    for (let j = 0; j < images.length; j++) {
      if (images[j].id === memeLikesList[i].memeId) {
        memesWithLikes.push(images[j]);
      }
    }
  }
}
return memesWithLikes;
}

 render() {
         const memesList = !this.state?.showMemesWithHighLikes ? this.props.images : 
          this.getMemesWithHigherLikes();
```

Comment: On your next post on SO, I'd say to you to focus more on describing the problem rather than describing the context your solution is related.

Comment: Hey Stephanie. I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. When you step through this code in a debugger, which line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: The code works fine. I want to add the ability to save a meme(image) that's been changed and display it after it has been changed. What I have now all works but I'm only able to download the image(as an svg) after it has been changed.

Comment: Not sure if this is a bit more clear.